# Restricting input in VBA userform textboxes to only numbers

Tags: vba, textbox, userform

I created a userform with a bunch of textboxes that I want to restrict to only being doubles.  Instead of adding an IsNumeric() for each of the textboxes, is there something like a Userform_Change() function where I can pass in the inputted text or can I change something in the textbox properties to only allow numbers?

Also if the number check is good, is the value in the textbox still a string or will Excel know it's a number when I copy it to a cell in a worksheet?

Answer (score -1):

Textboxes can be configured to accept numbers only (and passwords as well). For instance Notepad is a big textbox. In Windows they are called Edit Controls (and Rich Edit Controls support nearly everything a Edit Control does).

So the Window style is

ES_NUMBER 
Allows only digits to be entered into the edit control. Note that, even with this set, it is still possible to paste non-digits into the edit control.
To change this style after the control has been created, use `SetWindowLong`.

See the Declare statement in VBA.

Comment: You can do it Windows' way or your own way.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand.  So how do you do this in VBA.  Are ES_NUMBER and setwindowlong properties of textboxes?